# Bootstrap Form checkbox and dropdown are not properly aligned with their labels

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-core

As you can see in the picture below, the input tag aligns properly with its label. But the dropdown is not horizontally in the same line as its label; it's a bit upward vertically. Same is true for the checkbox. I would like to see them exactly in the same line as their labels. I'm using ASP.NET Core that comes with latest version of Bootstrap by default. Issue probably is not related to ASP.NET, but just in case, following is the `Form` in ASP.NET where tag helpers are used. **NOTE**: The model property Test1 in my ASP.NET model is of type bool and therefore the ASP.NET render `<input asp-for="Test1" class="form-control" style="zoom:0.5;" />` as a checkbox. But that, I think, is not relevant here.

```
<form asp-controller="myController" asp-action="myAction" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ProjectTitle" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="ProjectTitle" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ProjectTitle" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="SelectedProjStatus" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select asp-for="SelectedProjStatus" asp-items="Model.lstProjStatuses"></select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Test1" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input asp-for="Test1" class="form-control" style="zoom:0.5;" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Test1" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you customized bootstrap at all?

Comment: @DavidWhitlock No, I have not.

Comment: Try adding `class="form-control"` to the select tag

Comment: @DavidWhitlock Your suggestion fixed the `select tag` alignment (thank you). But, the checkbox issue is still there.

Comment: Maybe adding `type="checkbox"` in the input tag will help. You can find more info at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: @DavidWhitlock Adding `type="checkbox"` did not help. The link you provided seem to indicate it should have worked, but no luck in my case.